# How can I override Perl's open() function but use the same filehandle for testing?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I am currently adding some unit tests to some legacy code and I find myself with the need to override an open function. The live code looks something like this.

```
if ( !open( F, $filetoopen) ){
    # do stuff with <F>
}
```

What I want to do is make sure that "F" contains a file handle that I have provided from my tests rather than what it thinks its opening.

I have the following code in my .t file...

```
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::open = sub { open(F,$testfiletoopen); };
};
```

... it does work and the code in test finishes up reading from my test file. However it will only continue to work as long as I use  the same filehandle name "F" as the code in test.

If there a way to make this test code less fragile so that if the filehandle name is changed in the live code the test won't fail?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you simply use the parameters your live code provides to open?

```
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::open = sub { open $_[0], $newfilename };
};
```

Keep in mind that this will break horribly as soon as you use the three-argument-form of open. If anything, this question offers yet more prove that the three-argument version is superior.

Comment: Thanks thats nearly what I need  sub {open (@_[0],$newfilename) };  works

Comment: Agreed, you should use the three argument form of open, and use lexical file handles:  ... sub { open $_[0], $_[1], $newfilename }

Comment: The good thing is that if you have small things to test you can control your input and actually know which form of `open` to expect. And it is possible to use this to validate which files the actual code tries to open. Very helpful answer, thanks a lot! =)